# Android studio XML textview on an imageview

Tags: java, android, xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="433dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/list_number_placeholder"
            android:textColor="@color/bar_separator_color"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
            />
```

I have a question i cant get the text on my imageview, i think its something with the layers. Please help me..

im btw a beginner in Android studio XD

Comment: Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. It will overlay the elements, the you can order them as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using **LinearLayout** which stacks your view one by one, either in **horizontal** direction or **vertical** direction (Orientation).

So use **RelativeLayout** instead if you want views overlapping.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="433dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/list_number_placeholder"
            android:textColor="@color/bar_separator_color"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Linear Layout to Relative layout

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="433dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/list_number_placeholder"
        android:textColor="@color/bar_separator_color"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**Well You are better to use framelayout **. I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks! you helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

its not good way. better print something with java like:

```
LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);

myText = new TextView(this);
myText.setText("My Text");

lView.addView(myText);

setContentView(lView);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="433dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="hii" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="yo"
            android:textColor="@color/bg_login"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/picture"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My super text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="48sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/controls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#7f000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code put the text in the middle of the image as you've requested for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/nations"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="433dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="image" />

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/list_number_placeholder"
        android:textColor="@color/bar_separator_color"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        /></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```